Razor Pages and the MVVM Pattern: Exploring the Relationship (MVC or MVVM or ...)
I am confused about the architecture of Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core. Some sources claim that Razor Pages adhere to the MVC pattern, while others argue that they follow the MVVM pattern. Can someone clarify the architecture of Razor Pages and explain whether they should be considered as part of the MVC pattern, MVVM pattern, or something else entirely?
my opinion:
I don't believe it follows the MVVM pattern because requests are made inside the page model (the ViewModel of MVVM) rather than inside the view. Therefore, it does not adhere to MVVM principles.
It appears to be an MVC structure with the C and M components within the page model.

some related links
With regards to razor, what is difference between .NET MVC support for razor vs .NET razor pages and is there anything called .NET MVC razor pages?
WPF MVVM vs Razor Page MVVM

no controller -> not MVC as there's no C. It's a web app but not SPA so that it has data within itself -> not MVVM as model-view-viewmodel only has container to put data and view binding model property. I prefer to call it an alternative to the traditional MVC because it just combine controller + view together(cshtml + corresponding cshtml.cs)

linguistics... MVC is a design architecture, but it's also a sort of Microsoft brand name for a framework.


It appears to be an MVC structure with the C and M components within
the page model.

This is how I see Razor Pages, as I mentioned in one of the accepted answers you linked to. Each page has its own controller, implemented as a PageModel class, which represents an example of the Page Controller pattern. It is responsible for processing input from the request and preparing a model for the view (the .cshtml file). The only real difference between MVC and Razor Pages is that an MVC controller is typically scoped to an entity rather than a single page, although there is nothing to stop you scoping an MVC controller to an endpoint.


In my humble opinion, Razor Page application shouldn't be an MVC application, because it doesn't contain Controller in the project, which means it's no C here. In the meantime, asp.net core has a separate MVC application template which uses builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews + app.MapControllerRoute instead of builder.Services.AddRazorPages() + app.MapRazorPages().
Data handling in MVC and MVVC:
MVC has controller to handle data, maybe it has service layer and Repo layer as well, then view binds model, in the controller we need to prepare all data and then fill the model so that we can use codes like "asp-for = @model.property" to display data. If we want to update the view, we need to contact controller or write JS code to operate on DOM.
For MVVM, it doesn't contain a controller, so that the app itself should handle the "routing", then it uses ViewModel to prepare the required data. It does benefit for "loose coupling". Because the view has data-binding to ViewModel, one view has a corresponding ViewModel to collect required data and exposing many properties which is filled with data that already handled. We don't need to operate DOM. This design pattern is always used in Single Page Application which working on frontend - backend api server mode. We have view codes in a separate app while the data are sent from external app. In this aspect, Razor Page application looks similar to MVVM, as it handles routing without controller, it defines many properties in PageModel(e.g Index.cshtml.cs) and bind the properties in View, but essentially the Views and ViewModel are all from the server web app, here the ViewModel is a combination of Controller + Model, so that it's a fake ViewModel.
Summary: I prefer to call Razor Page web application as an alternative to the traditional MVC, it's not an MVC app since it doesn't have controller, it combines the Controller(routing + data gathering and handling) and the View together, it requires less codes to realize the same feature like what MVC can do. But it's a web app as well as MVC application. It's also similar to MVVM pattern which handles the routing without controller and has data-binding, but since it's not SPA and the data is gathered from the web app internally but not from external system, it shouldn't be MVVM as MVVM(model-view-viewmodel) doesn't have data source, it should collect data in ViewModel from external resource.

The PageModel class in Razor Pages is an example of the Page Controller pattern. The ASP.NET implementation of MVC has classes named with the Controller suffix, but that's an implementation-specific convention, not a requirement for a framework to meet the MVC pattern.
